# How exactly do objects move

Tags: kinematics

Suppose I have a piece of steel that is made up of one row of 100 atoms. Now, suppose I try to slide it across a surface by pushing it forward, the atom I come into contact with (the last atom in the row) can only move forward if the atom in front of it moves forward, and so on. So,  is motion like a train, in which between carriages(atoms being our carriages) there are links that can stretch and vibrate; I know that on an atomic level atoms have vibrational and stretch energy.

I guess what I am asking is, when objects move, is there a constant shortening and lengthening of the object until it comes to rest.

Sorry if my question is incredibly stupid and overlooking something very basic.

Comment: Do you understand how sound propagates?

Comment: Not particularly.

Comment: +1, Actually, there is shortening and lengthening only when there is an acceleration. Although these things are incredibly hard to do calculate, so we use approximate mathematical models like a rigid body. There is no such thing as a point particle as well, but it is a mathematical model used to approximate real world objects and YES, real world is indeed fascinating if you learn how to look at it.

Answer (score 4):

First, if you only have one line of atoms in the three-dimensional space, it will almost certainly bend if you push it. So it's better to make the sequence thicker. But let's assume that you have guaranteed that the thing doesn't bend.

It looks like this:

[image]

The boxes represent the individual atoms. And the springs represent some forces between the atoms. The springs may be very stiff so their length is almost constant. But it is not exactly constant.

When you push from the left side, the first atom may be moved immediately, but the other atoms are still sitting on their places. However, the spring between the first and second atom gets shorter by $\Delta x$, some change of the length. This has the implication that there is a force acting on the second atom
$$ F = k\cdot \Delta x$$
where $k$ is a constant characteristic for the spring, the spring constant, determining how stiff it is. When this force acts on the second atom, its location $x_2$ will accelerate into the right side. After some time, it will move to the right side a little bit, and shorten the spring between the 2nd and 3rd spring, and so on. The more you pushed (by force, or by $\Delta x$), the greater $\Delta x$ was for the first atom, and the greater force was exerted by the first spring etc.

With a certain speed, the signal is moving towards the right side. All the springs want to restore their original length. But they may do so while moving around. As a result, some sine waves – sound – are propagating along the chain of the atoms. These waves may be described by the "wave equation".

However, there is also some friction or dissipation. When the atoms accelerate or the length of the spring is changing, there is a friction that produces some heat – nonzero probability to emit a photon, a particle of light etc. These friction terms mean that the sound waves don't  oscillate forever. They get weaker with time.

The picture above showed "springs" between the atoms. This was just to explain the behavior of atoms in terms of something we know from the everyday life. But the actual explanatory reduction goes in the opposite direction: the metallic springs themselves are composed of atoms that repel and attract and these elementary forces between the adjacent atoms are electromagnetic and "fundamental", while the forces from springs are "composite" and made out of the simpler electromagnetic forces.

Comment: Great answer. Motion is so fascinating on the micro-level. I mean we have everyday experiences with it but intuition only goes so far when looking at a micro-level.

Answer (score 0):

In my mind, this is neither a stupid question nor would I know of an explicit answer easily available to look up. I will try to formulate an answer, but I am open to criticism and corrections :)

At an atomic level, repulsion between atoms occurs mainly due to the electrodynamic repulsion between the electrons forming the electronic shells of the atoms. So moving one atom towards another will beginning at some distance create a repulsive force. For molecules, everything is a bit more complicated, but looking up something like the Lennard-Jones potential might give an idea of what I am talking about. If you have a solid which is kept together by some form of bound and you push at some point, on an atomic level the push is transferred onto the whole body successively from atom to atom by those small scale forces between the atoms. The image of a train with carriages is not bad, in physics a common picture is often to imagine a solid body being made out of small balls connected with springs which connect them with their neighbours.

So no, there is no constant shortening and lengthening on a macroscopic scale, but yes, on a microscopic scale, atoms or molecules might change their respective distances to transfer the force exerted on the body on one point to the rest of the body.