# How force affect the objects that we apply on?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, kinematics, speed

Why do things get accelerated rather than do a moving at constant speed when we apply a force on them? How my force affect the object at atomic level? Does it increase the kinetic energy of atoms ? If it does, why ı can't observe the same event when ı heat them(cus both of these increase the kinetic energy)?

Comment: Very related question : https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/258977/how-exactly-do-objects-move?rq=1

Comment: Also, keep in mind that heat increases the **random kinetic energy** of the particles.

Comment: thank you for directing:)

Answer (score 0):

> Why do things get accelerated rather than do a moving at constant
>   speed when we apply a force on them?

They accelerate if there is a *net force* applied to them per Newton's second law, $F_{net}=ma$. Things remain stationary or move with constant velocity when there is either no force applied, or if the *net force* applied is zero, per Newton's first law.

> How my force affect the object at atomic level? Does it increase the
>   kinetic energy of atoms ? If it does, why ı can't observe the same
>   event when ı heat them(cus both of these increase the kinetic energy)?

Objects have internal energy, the microscopic kinetic and potential energies of the atoms and molecules of the object. Your force can have an effect on those energies. For example, if the force causes an object to deform at the same time as it causes it to accelerate, it can increase the microscopic kinetic energies of the atoms due to internal friction. You can't "see" the increase in the microscopic kinetic energy but you might be able to measure an increase in temperature of the object because of the increase in kinetic energy.

You can also increase the internal microscopic kinetic energy of the atoms an molecules by means of heating the object, i.e., exposing the object to something else at a higher temperature. Of course increasing the kinetic energy by means of heat does not cause the object as a whole to accelerate, as when you apply a force.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I thought that I couldn't explain my self after your answer. I already familiar with Newton laws of motion and know it is an empirical formulation as well. I don't know whether researcing the reasons of how laws works extensively is true but I can't understand this intuitivly. I continue applying same force on something its velocity get increased through the time. I just wonder approach of physicist about it. dunno if it sounds so stupid.

Comment: @CrushedBanana In that case I'm afraid I really don't understand what it is you don't understand. So I guess I can't help you.